# How can I open front camera using xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, front-camera

I want to open the front camera of my device for face verification in my app with a title "Smile for the camera".How can I do this, currently I am getting the back camera default, how do I change to front camera and also hide the back camera option.

please help me

Here is my code to open camera

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
  StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code?

Comment: @Saadi I want to open the front camera

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have to iterate through the available hardware devices that match the identifier of camera.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26150057/4486115) SO answer suggests:

```
Camera.CameraInfo camInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo ();
for (int i = 0; i < Camera.NumberOfCameras; i++) {
    Camera.GetCameraInfo (i, camInfo);
    if (camInfo.Facing == CameraFacing.Front){
        try {
            return Camera.Open(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log or something
        }
    }
}
return null;
```

There's also a question on the xamarin forums regarding this which appeared to give a similar approach, [can be found here.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29173/choose-between-front-and-back-camera-for-video-capture)

Comment: I got an exception in  return Camera.Open(i);

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT I am fix that exception